# My app crashes when decoding file using BitmapFactory

Tags: java, android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I have an app that has multiple activities. Those activities contain an imageview that loads an image from a specified path on the phone (DCIM/Camera/Pic123.jpg), by using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(). The problem is, is that if I close out of the activities in and out really quickly, the app crashes!

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/camera/TapTrack");
File file;
file = new File(picturesDirectoryPath, "TapTrack_164.jpg"); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

the app crashes on this line 4th line of code. So my question is, does anyone know any way I can make the decodeFile process more efficient? Or are there any alternatives to the BitmapFactory?

Comment: Can you post your logcat output?

Comment: Not exactly, because my app uses the camera heavily, I have to run it from my phone every time. So when it crashes, it's on my phone rather than on the AVD.

Comment: You'd still get a stacktrace in `adb logcat`

Comment: Where would I view it then? Do I need to install something?

Comment: Using both Eclipse and Android Studio you should see a log whenever your app is running. Also, if you have the SDK downloaded, from a terminal window in the `platform-tools` folder you can run `adb logcat` when your device is plugged in

Comment: To get logcat see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: How big is that file? You will have an out of memory error. Resize the image before putting it in an ImageView. Try your code with a very small jpg first.

Comment: The file is the default size of a picture taken on the camera. I'm assuming that's way too big?